# VS Code Jupyter Extension Markdown Math Not Rendering

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

Whenever I try to place something in math mode for Markdown in an `.ipynb` file and submit it as a cell, it does not render it. In fact, it seems to render everything in Markdown except for the things with math mode.

For example entering this:

```
# This is a title

- This is in a bullet point
- This should be in inline `math mode`: $e^{i\pi} = -1$

#### This Should be in Math Mode:
$$\Sigma_{i = 0}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
```

I get this:

[image: screenshot of vs code]

I am using:

```
Version: 1.52.0-insider (user setup)
Commit: ee46c1f89ebb213e0827886f1688c0fbb55be49f
Date: 2020-11-13T05:37:45.836Z
Electron: 9.3.3
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

The Jupyter extension is `v2020.11.358541065`